# Creating a 2D array of a class that returns an array of char

Tags: java, arrays

I have been trying desperately to create a 2D array of chars by using classes however I keep getting stuck at the same point where the printed array is a combination of letters and numbers. I have tried using the toString() with System.out.print(board) however this does not seem to make any difference. I have a completely functional version of my program using simply an array of chars. However, the task I have to complete requires printing chars by using an array of a class (in this case GameItem).

My Display method is as follows:

```
private void display(){
    board = new GameItem[4][4];
    for(int i=0; i<board.length; i++) {          
        for(int j=0; j<board.length; j++) {             
            board[i][j] = GameItem.Gold;                    
            System.out.print(board);
        }      
        System.out.print("\n");
    }    
}
```

and my GameItem class contains:

```
public class GameItem {

    static GameItem Gold = new GameItem ('G');      
    public GameItem(char c){}       
}
```

Note that I am required to use the constructor.

Comment: Your requirements as well as what you're trying to do - is not clear.

Comment: Currently you are trying to print the whole board at every iteration, that's not what you want. Print just the single `GameItem`. In the `GameItem` constructor you should store the `char c` to a private field. Then you can implement `toString()` e.g. with `return String.valueOf(c);` Also are you sure you want to create a new array in a method called `display()`?

Comment: @alfasin please tell me what you don't understand and I will explain.